# Setting multiple UIBarButtonItems fails on device, but not on simulator

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios5, uibarbuttonitem, ios-simulator

I'm consistently running into an invalid selector exception when I attempt to set multiple UIBarButtonItems in MonoTouch.

In the simulator, there are no issues at all. Each button I add works correctly. Only when I deploy to a test device (iPhone 3G with iOS 4.2.1 installed) does it throw this error:

-[UINavigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xef7af0

I have tried using the RightBarButtonItems property and the explicit SetRightBarButtonItems method, passing a UIBarButtonItem[] instance in each case.

Maybe the way to get around this is to use a ToolBar with a custom view, but I'd rather just use the API as advertised, especially if it works correctly in the simulator.

Anyone run into this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using MonoTouch 5.0 and the latest iOS SDK (5) and Xcode 4.2.

The `setRightBarButtonItems:animated:` selector is new in iOS5. This means it will work in the simulator, which likely defaults to **5.0**. However this won't work in older releases of iOS (e.g. like 4.2.1).

At this stage you have two choices:

- avoid iOS5 features; or
- detect, at runtime, which version of iOS is being used and adjust your application to what's available.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://osmorphis.blogspot.com/2009/05/multiple-buttons-on-navigation-bar.html

It works if you want to add multiple right buttons for iOS < 5.0